# How to set the zIndex on the drawer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, z-index

I am trying to acheive the `clipped under the app bar` style temporary drawer. But I can't seem to be able to set the z index on the temporary drawer.

The temporary drawer in material-ui has the z-index of the `modal` component which is `1300` as mentioned in the issue I raised here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/22562.

So, if I use the approach given in the documentation of setting the appbar zIndex to `theme.zIndex.modal + 1`, I can get the 'clipped under the app bar` effect. But that would also mean that my appbar would be above all my modals. Which is not what I desire.

So, I wanted to set my temporary drawer to z-index of `1250` and my appbar's z-index to `1251` to get the desired effect without any side-effects.

I am trying to set the zIndex with `makeStyles` hook as you can see in the sandbox and also the snippet below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    zIndex: 1251
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    zIndex: 1250
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  }
}));
```

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
   .
   .
   .
</AppBar>
```

```
<Drawer
  className={classes.drawer}
  open={true}
  classes={{
    paper: classes.drawerPaper
  }}
>
   .
   .
   .
</Drawer>
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rq1fj?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `important!` you can override `zIndex` either by using Material-UI theme API or by inlining styles.

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  zIndex: {
    appBar: 1251,
    modal: 1250,
  }
});

...

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Demo />
</ThemeProvider>,
```

The downside of this approach is that the styles is applied to all modals, so your actual modals are now below the `AppBar` which may not be what you want.

The second approach is to inline css style by passing styling object in the style props of your component

```js
<AppBar
  className={classes.appBar}
  style={{ zIndex: 1251 }}
>
</AppBar>
<Drawer
  className={classes.drawer}
  style={{ zIndex: 1250 }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI - Overriding zIndex]

Comment: Yeah thanks, that seem to solve the issue. Weird that now my component has `className`, `classes` and `style` props.

Answer (score 4):

Your `z-index: 1250` is overriden by inline `z-index: 1300` addded by material-ui. You can override this inline style by adding `!important` to your custom `z-index`.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: 1251
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    zIndex: "1250 !important"
  },
  ...
}));
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that if you really want to set some style in css, you can use the `!important` syntax. But I am not a big fan of using it. Is there some other way?

Comment: The goal is to override that inline style; you can create an external css file and use a more specific selector.