# The difference between specificity and implementation of styles -> global, theme, hooks, custom css and inline styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Lately I have been experimenting with material-ui and have had some issues dealing with how to style the components. Although majority of the material-ui way of styling is really intuitive and easy to figure out, it can get a little confusing since there are so many ways to style a component. Also there seem to be some cases when only one of the method is right and it is tedious to see which is the right one by trial and error, or posting a question on stackoverflow.

Like in the question [How to set the zIndex on the drawer component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855547/how-to-set-the-zindex-on-the-drawer-component/63856957#63856957) I asked, the only way to set the z-index of the component was through inline style using `style` props. Since material-ui it seems is setting the style of the drawer component using inline style. Which is confusing to me as I thought that there was a "global" style for each component css "class" and it passed those css "classes" and set the styles on the component. So now I have `className`, `classes` and `style` props on my component to set its style.

So the question is -> How to know which method (theme, global, inline) material-ui is using to set a specific style on the component and therefore know which method (theme, global, hooks, custom css file, inline) I can use to change that specific style.

And also what is the specificity of those methods, obviously the inline will have the most, but regarding the other (theme, global, hooks and custom css file)

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for the reply. Is it only Modal that uses inline styles? or is there any other component? Since I don't think there is anything about it in the official docs. Also, I do understand the css specificity rules, but was confused by the css injection order stuff specified in the docs https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order  (especially the insertion point stuff).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks a lot again for all your help. I was worried about it because I use `React CSS` module along with material-ui style `hooks (makeStyles, withStyles, etc)` . I use `mui hooks` for setting the styles that are either dynamic or based on the theme, and use `React CSS module` for setting all other styles. I do so because I don't like jss cluttering my business logic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of inline styles within Material-UI is very rare. `Modal` (which is used by `Drawer`) was changed from using CSS classes to using inline styles in v4 in order to reduce the bundle size for developers using Material-UI's `Modal` as a base for building other modals without using any of the other Material-UI code. Almost all styling in Material-UI is done via CSS classes generated using [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/). Most of the other cases of inline styles are for dynamically determined positioning (e.g. Popper and Popover) or animation for transitions. It is rare to be trying to override those other cases of inline styles.

To better understand specificity, I recommend reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. When specificity is otherwise the same, the order of the style sheets determines which one wins (the last one wins) -- that is why injection order matters (as indicated in the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order). You generally only need to worry about that when you are using CSS from one source (e.g. styled-components or emotion) to override CSS from another source (e.g. the default Material-UI styles generated by JSS).