# How to set the zIndex on the drawer component of variant "temporary" in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to implement "temporary" drawer clipped under the app bar (Note: drawer variant 'temporary' and clipped under app-bar).

See to an earlier post on this subject for more context:
[How to set the zIndex on the drawer component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855547/how-to-set-the-zindex-on-the-drawer-component) .
The solution suggested was to override drawer zIndex using !important.

But I get typescript error
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-m9kxd?file=/demo.tsx&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `zIndex` property on the `Drawer` and set the `zIndex` of `appBar` to something greater (I tried `1500` and it worked)

Comment: Actually, any number above `1300` should work. Reason: `Drawer` wrapper has an inline style with `z-index: 1300`

Comment: 1300 is z-index for modal also ( drawer of variant temporary is modal internally). Now, If i set z-index on appBar, I will have issue with other modals from menu items on app bar. They need to stay above appBar.